# Dynamic nested routes in Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

I've got to grips with static routes and dynamic routes in Nuxt.

However, I'm trying to work out if it's possible to have effectively unlimited nested pages.

For example, in a standard CMS such as Wordpress I can define a deep nest of pages such as:

```
*hostname.com/page/other-page/another/yet-another/one-more/final-page*
```

I suppose I could define an unnecessarily deep page structure, such as:

```
- /_level1
   - index.vue
   /_level2
      - index.vue
      / _level3
         - index.vue
         /level4
            -index.vue
```

...and so on. But this doesn't feel particularly efficient or scalable, and introduces lots of duplicate code and maintenance problems.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use nested routes with the "children" option.

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/user/:id', component: User,
      children: [
        {
          // UserProfile will be rendered inside User's <router-view>
          // when /user/:id/profile is matched
          path: 'profile',
          component: UserProfile
        },
        {
          // UserPosts will be rendered inside User's <router-view>
          // when /user/:id/posts is matched
          path: 'posts',
          component: UserPosts
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
})
```

You can also import child routes from a separate file.

```
import UserRoutes from "./users/router.js"


const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/user/:id', component: User,
      children: UserRoutes
    }
  ]
})
```

Then in your users/router.js:

```
export default [
  {
    // UserProfile will be rendered inside User's <router-view>
    // when /user/:id/profile is matched
    path: 'profile',
    component: UserProfile
  },
  {
    // UserPosts will be rendered inside User's <router-view>
    // when /user/:id/posts is matched
    path: 'posts',
    component: UserPosts
  }
]
```